# MailChimp form not registering Users as pending until they confirm by email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, gibbon

I am attempting to synchronize my apps user list with who is subscribed on MailChimp.

We are using the [Gibbon gem](https://github.com/amro/gibbon) with Rails 4. Everything works fine, I can view status of a user based on their email address and determine if they are subscribed, pending or nil. Users can sign up via a link to MailChimp's online form or by checking the opt-in box within our web app.

The issue is, that if a user subscribes via the MailChimp link, the MailChimp API does not recognize them as pending. As a result, our app receives nil, instead of "pending" which is what happens if they sign up via the checkbox.

Since the app receives the response `nil` it indicates to the user that they should check the box to sign-up for the newsletter which is awk, since they already signed up once.

Beyond that, if the user checks the box having already signed up directly with MailChimp, they get rejected with a 400 error since MailChimp already has the email address.

My goal is to be able to reflect accurately in the app when a user is subscribed, pending, etc on MailChimp.

Error and Full trace below:

> .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gibbon-2.0.0/lib/gibbon/api_request.rb:100:in `handle_error'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gibbon-2.0.0/lib/gibbon/api_request.rb:16:in`rescue in post'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gibbon-2.0.0/lib/gibbon/api_request.rb:10:in `post'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gibbon-2.0.0/lib/gibbon/request.rb:28:in`create'
>   app/models/user.rb:60:in `add_to_mailchimp'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:430:in`block in make_lambda'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:237:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:237:in`block in halting'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in`block in call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.3/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in`run_validations!'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.3/lib/active_model/validations.rb:334:in `valid?'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:58:in`valid?'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:83:in `perform_validations'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:37:in`save'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in`block (2 levels) in save'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in`transaction'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in`with_transaction_returning_status'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block in save'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:301:in`rollback_active_record_state!'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `save'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:252:in`block in update'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in`block in transaction'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in`transaction'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in`with_transaction_returning_status'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:250:in `update'
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:20:in`update'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in`process_action'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in`block in process_action'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in`run_callbacks'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in`process_action'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in`block in instrument'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in`instrument'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in`process_action'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/searchkick-0.8.7/lib/searchkick/logging.rb:107:in `process_action'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in`process_action'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in`process'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in`dispatch'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in`serve'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in`each'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-pjax-0.8.0/lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bullet-4.14.7/lib/bullet/rack.rb:12:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`catch'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/remotipart-1.2.1/lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in`context'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in`block in call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:84:in `run_callbacks'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rollbar-1.5.3/lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:24:in `block in call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rollbar-1.5.3/lib/rollbar.rb:799:in`scoped'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rollbar-1.5.3/lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:22:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rollbar-1.5.3/lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb:22:in `call_with_rollbar'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`block in tagged'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`tagged'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ahoy_matey-1.1.1/lib/ahoy/engine.rb:20:in`call_with_quiet_ahoy'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/request_store-1.1.0/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:8:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in`call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:507:in`handle_request'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:262:in`block in run'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `call'
>   .bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in`block in spawn_thread'

Comment: The pending status means "pending double opt-in confirmation", so if someone signs up via the link (and the form is set to require confirmation), they should show up as pending. If that's not what you're experiencing, you should email support and see if they can clear it up for you.

Comment: Thanks Pete, I just reached out to them and they are looking into it.